# how to update infopath form library item field programatically?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I was successfully able to update one of the fields (which was of type boolean) from **infopath** for library item  using sharepoint object Model as if it was a list item.

But for another field which is of type text, the same code just gets executed but does not change the field value !!!!

I am using following code, which works for that boolean field but for another field of type string , not sure why it is not working. Any idea ?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()

{ 
SPWeb web;

SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"); 
web = site.OpenWeb();

SPList formLibList = web.Lists["FormLibraryName"];

SPQuery query = new SPQuery(); query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + titleName + "</Value></Eq></Where>"; 
web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
SPListItemCollection col = formLibList.GetItems(query);

if (col.Count > 0) 
{

col[0]["CustomerName"] = "test customer name"; 
col[0].Update();

}

web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true; web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; 
});
```

Thanks,

Nikhil

Comment: Got it, i had to declar SPListItem and set it instead of directly modifying list item collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to declare SPListItem and set it instead of directly modifying list item collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your question (you already found the solution yourself), but you may want to put your SPSite and SPWeb objects in a using block. In your example code you are not disposing them, which results in a memory leak. The correct way would be like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            // the rest of your code
        }
    }
});
```